# o365 - Unable to delete items from mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365

a user is not able to delete items from his mailbox .  I have tried to force this by running command.  I have tried this both OWA and Outlook. unfortunately no luck.

```
Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity user@domain.com
```

User properties :

```
Get-Mailbox "user" |FL Name,LitigationHoldEnabled,LitigationHoldDate,LitigationHoldOwner,LitigationHoldDuration,InPlaceHolds

Name                   : user
LitigationHoldEnabled  : True
LitigationHoldDate     : 5/3/2018 10:29:09 AM
LitigationHoldOwner    : xxxx
LitigationHoldDuration : Unlimited
InPlaceHolds           : {}



Get-MailboxStatistics "user" | FL Name,DeletedItemCount,ItemCount,TotalDeletedItemSize,TotalItemSize

DeletedItemCount     : 227953
ItemCount            : 33425
TotalDeletedItemSize : 100 GB (107,374,277,766 bytes)
TotalItemSize        : 14.61 GB (15,687,850,951 bytes)



Get-Mailbox "user" | FL Name,RecoverableItemsQuota,RecoverableItemsWarningQuota


Name                         : user
RecoverableItemsQuota        : 100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)
RecoverableItemsWarningQuota : 90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)


Get-Mailbox "user" |fl Name, *archive*

Name                        : user
ArchiveDatabase             : xxxxxx
ArchiveDatabaseGuid         : 4540c7b0-1edf-4ffd-94d9-64478a14a879
ArchiveGuid                 : c74725e7-d3a4-4931-9fc4-774afdb6e68e
ArchiveName                 : {Personal Archive - User)}
JournalArchiveAddress       : 
ArchiveQuota                : 100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)
ArchiveWarningQuota         : 90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)
ArchiveDomain               : 
ArchiveStatus               : Active
ArchiveState                : Local
AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled : False
DisabledArchiveDatabase     : 
DisabledArchiveGuid         : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ArchiveRelease              :
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any error message when delete email?

From the cmdlets, we could know the followings:

1. This mailbox is in litigation hold. In this situation the deleted items are put on hold and are not purged from the mailbox.
2. TotalDeletedItemSize is reached the maximum amount of 100GB.

And you could resolve this issue by two methods:

1. Remove hold
2. Enable the archive mailbox and turn on auto-expanding archiving

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4ec0cea2-6ae1-4082-84fc-fe35df287531/totaldeleteditemsize-how-does-it-works?forum=exchange2010

Comment: already Enable the archive mailbox. due to users’s mailbox has already reached the Recoverable Items folder quota of 100 GB its not working archiving function. Finally , I need to open ticket for increase quota limit.  Am I correct ?

Comment: When an archive mailbox exceeds the specified archive quota, messages are no longer moved to the archive, a warning event is logged in the Application event log, and a quota message is sent to the mailbox user. Yes, you need to increase quota to unlimited.